# Rails testing - no rows returned when querying the database during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I've made fixtures for some (not all) of my models, and have written tests in which objects of other models are created and saved. I'm using the standard testing system built into Rails (`rake test`). In one of my tests I've called `debugger`.

In the debugger, calling `Login.all` returns two logins which were created in the test. However, if I connect to the database (a PostgreSQL database, I'm connecting using pgAdmin 3) and do a `select * from logins`, no rows are returned.

I know this is the right database because my fixtures are all there (eg. if I run `select * from users`, all of my fixture users appear).

I assumed that when I called `#save` on an ActiveRecord object during a test, it would actually insert it into the database. Is this assumption incorrect, or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you connect, are you in `test` environment or in `development`/`production` environment?

Comment: @alestanis - definitely `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out each test runs in a transaction. When the debugger is hit, the transaction hasn't been committed yet so nothing shows up in the database. The transaction can be manually committed (but then the data can't be rolled back after the test completes, so it could clash with other tests).